# Preventing an element having duplicate classnames

Tags: javascript

I would like to prevent duplicate classnames on an element using JavaScript.

When I run the following code, I get the classname `"Test 1"` twice.

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="foo">Hey</div>
</body>
```

and my Javascript:

```
function addClass(element, myClass) {
   var add = element.className += ' ' + myClass; 
}

addClass(foo,'Test1');
addClass(foo,'Test1');
addClass(foo, 'Test2');
```

I would like my result to be:

```
<div id="foo" class=" Test1 Test2">Hey</div>
```

and not

```
<div id="foo" class=" Test1 Test1 Test2">Hey</div>
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: So check the `className` property for the presence of the class you are adding.

Comment: This might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `string.contains()` method when adding the class; try something like

```
function addClass(element, myClass) {
   if(!element.className.contains(myClass))
       element.className += ' ' + myClass; 
}
```

EDIT

Use `string.split(" ")` to break the class names up (to avoid matching partial class names), then use `indexOf` to check to see if the class has been added already. Something like

```
function addClass(element, myClass) {
   if(element.className.split(" ").indexOf(myClass)==-1)
       element.className += ' ' + myClass; 
}
```

Comment: This is good in all cases except when it adds a class whose name is a substring of a previously added class.

Comment: `string.contains()` is only supported by firefox at the moment.

Comment: Why not `element.className.indexOf(myClass) === -1`? But still, what @Tap said is true.

Comment: Ah sorry, they must have added it.  Still, it's not supported in ie9, and shouldn't be used for general purpose sites yet.

Comment: The `split(" ")` is very clever. +1

Answer (score 3):

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/NN5Cv/1/)

Use `indexOf()` to see if it already has that class. Note that the solution by itself would cause problems when having classes that contain part of another, so I've slightly changed it (New solution is a little ugly but meh)

```
function addClass(element, myClass) {
   if((" " +element.className+ " ").indexOf(" "+myClass+" ") == -1)
       element.className += ' ' + myClass; 
}
```

Comment: Still, what if the element has a class of `grapefrut` and he wants to add the class `ape`? The script won't allow him to.

Comment: Notice that this will fail if you have the class `btn-dark` and try to add `btn` for instance.

Comment: @Zenith What about `class="myClass otherClass"` or `class="otherClass myClass"`?

Comment: @Zenith Still isn't reliable if the element already has classes defined initially.

Comment: @DJDavid98 How isn't it exactly? Try it out for yourself http://jsfiddle.net/NN5Cv/2/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you are adding a class you want that class to have precedence- if it exists already but was superceded in the cascade by another class, move the old instance to the end of the class definitition-

```
function addCLass(who,cname){
    var rx= RegExp('\\b'+cname+'\\b','g'),
    C=who.className.replace(rx,'').split(/\s+/).push(cname);
    who.className= C.join(' ');
}
```